# Magento 2.2 listing page products sort by price is incorrect

Tags: magento2, price, sorting

I'm using Magento CE 2.2.6
In front-end when we sort the category pages by price, the sorting happens wrongly. 
[image]
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Any other theme use or?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. This is a Magento issue it seems. I've encountered it in older versions as well.

Comment: I've used a custom theme. However this issue is reproduceble with vanila installation of Magento as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I investigated this seems to be a Magento core issue. 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18264

The fix for this is provided in below link.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/14ab8ace12f0e95a476675548d0712d5ecaf9a26#diff-5a30a751305f50e9d7bbd8a2576a2b46

> Fix:

Create a patch file in 'patches' folder inside your project directory and add the below content there.

```
--- /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Indexer/Price/Query/BaseFinalPrice.php   2018-10-25 17:11:00.749047680 +0530
+++ /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Indexer/Price/Query/BaseFinalPrice.php   2018-10-25 17:15:19.657517309 +0530
@@ -190,7 +190,7 @@
         $specialFromExpr = "{$specialFrom} IS NULL OR {$specialFromDate} <= {$currentDate}";
         $specialToExpr = "{$specialTo} IS NULL OR {$specialToDate} >= {$currentDate}";
         $specialPriceExpr = $connection->getCheckSql(
-            "{$specialPrice} IS NOT NULL AND {$specialFromExpr} AND {$specialToExpr}",
+            "{$specialPrice} IS NOT NULL AND ({$specialFromExpr}) AND ({$specialToExpr})",
             $specialPrice,
             $maxUnsignedBigint
         );
```

Once you create the patch file, then run a composer update (or install if you prefer) and then do a full reindex.

That's it. Hope this will help someone in need.

**NOTE: I have done this with Magento CE 2.2.6**

Comment: @JeevaChezhiyan: Glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by overriding \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar::setCollection.
I've tried it using an around or after plugin but this didn't work because $_collection is protected.

Change:

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
```

To something like:

```
class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{
...
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
                $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder() === 'price' ? 'special_price' : $this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
            }
```

And make a di.xml with

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="[YourVendor]\[YourModule]\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
```